# Tasks in CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE not being processed

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

I am trying to setup a dummy task in Celery that runs every 3 seconds but have had little success so far. This is the output I am getting:

[image]

I've set up celery as follows:

In **settings.py**:

```
from datetime import timedelta

BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
CELERY_IMPORTS = ("api.tasks")
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'add_job': {
        'task': 'add_job',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=3),
        'args': (16, 16)
    },
}
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC'
```

In **celery.py**:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'blogpodapi.settings')
app = Celery(
    'blogpodapi',
)

# Using a string here means the worker will not have to
# pickle the object when using Windows.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

In **tasks.py**

```
from celery.task import task

@task(name='add_job')
def add_job(x, y):
    r = x + y
    print "task arguments: {x}, {y}".format(x=x, y=y)
    print "task result: {r}".format(r=r)
    return r
```

Have I done anything wrong in the way that I have set it up?

Comment: I don't think you are getting any error. You just got a warning. And your celery is working just perfect without any error as the last line says that Celery is ready..!!

Comment: Ok thanks but why is the task not running? This is what's confusing me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay the very basic mistake I see is that most of the settings you've mentioned in your `settings.py` need to go in `celery.py`

Specially the `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE`

You are doing everything right, its just that your Celery *is waiting* for a task, which it is never receiving as it reads from celery.py and not from the settings.py. Hence nothing is happening.

See my **celery.py** and also the **settings.py** for a reference.

celery.py -> https://github.com/amyth/hammer/blob/master/config/celery.py

settings.py -> https://github.com/amyth/hammer/blob/master/config/settings.py

I have used **crontab**, coz I wanted to execute the task at a particular time of the day. So you don't need to worry about it. Yours is perfect for what you want to do.

Also from wherever whatever blog or tutorial you are following celery, check again what exactly are those settings required for and whether you need all all of them or not.

Answer (score 5):

Only answering because this was the first result when I searched on `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE`.

Reason it didn't work for me, was because it should be `CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE`

Comment: This was exactly it for me. The setting was `CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE` before Celery 4.0 so if you upgraded and didn't run the `celery upgrade settings proj/settings.py` command you'd end up with it not working.

Answer (score 1):

As to why your task does not run: it is not registered. If it was, the output of the Celery worker when it starts would be different - it would contain the following two lines (at least):

```
[tasks]
  . add_job
```